# Can't force inlining C++ function using Intel compiler

Tags: c++, inline, icc, intel-mic

I have a function defined as

```
inline void vec_add(__m512d &v3, const __m512d &v1, const __m512d &v2) {
    v3 = _mm512_add_pd(v1, v2);
}
```

(the `__m512d` is a native data type mapping to SIMD registers on Intel MIC architecture)

As this function is rather short and gets invoked frequently, I'd like it to be inlined at every invocation. But Intel's compiler seems reluctant to inline this function, even after I use the `-inline-forceinline` and `-O3` options. It reports that 'Forceinline not honored for call ...' while compiling. As I have to use some compiler specific features, e.g. the `__m512d` type, Intel compiler is my only option.

**More Info:**

The file structure is quite simple. The function `vec_add` is defined in a header file `mic.h`, which is included in another file `test.cc`. Function `vec_add` is just invoked repeatedly in a loop, and there're no function pointers involved. A **simplified** version of the code in `test.cc` looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i += 8) {
    // a, b, c are arrays of doubles, and each SIMD register can hold 8 doubles
    __mm512d va = _mm512_load_pd(a + i); // load SIMD register from memory
    __mm512d vb = _mm512_load_pd(b + i); // ditto
    __mm512d vc;
    vec_add(vc, va, vb); // store SIMD register to memory
    _mm512_store_pd(c + i, vc);
}
```

I've tried all kinds of hints, like `__attribute__((always_inline))`,`__forceinline`, and compiler option `-inline-forceinline`, none of which worked yet.

**Complete code**

I've put all the relevant code together in a simplified form. You can try it out if you have a Intel compiler. Use option `-Winline` to view inline reports and `-inline-forceinline` to force inlining.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

#define LEN (1<<20)

__attribute((target(mic)))
inline void vec_add(__m512d &v3, const __m512d &v1, const __m512d &v2) {
    v3 = _mm512_add_pd(v1, v2);
}

int main() {
    #pragma offload target(mic)
    {
        double *a = (double*)_mm_malloc(LEN*sizeof(double), 64);
        double *b = (double*)_mm_malloc(LEN*sizeof(double), 64);
        double *c = (double*)_mm_malloc(LEN*sizeof(double), 64);

        for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
            a[i] = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
            b[i] = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i += 8) {
            __m512d va = _mm512_load_pd(a + i);
            __m512d vb = _mm512_load_pd(b + i);
            __m512d vc;
            vec_add(vc, va, vb);
            _mm512_store_pd(c + i, vc);
        }

        _mm_free(a);
        _mm_free(b);
        _mm_free(c);
    }
}
```

**Configurations**

- Compiler: Intel compiler(ICC) 14.0.2
- Compile options: `-O3 -inline-forceinline -Winline`

Do you have any idea why this function can't be inlined? 
And how can I get it inlined after all(I don't want to turn to macros)?

Comment: Are you perchance taking the address of the function somewhere?

Comment: And have you tried using `inline __forceinline void vec_add(...)`?

Comment: Do you call the function in the same module?

Comment: Please show us the callsite

Comment: Including the file structure of your project (in which fille is the function, in which the caller and which headerfiles are included)

Comment: Have you checked the assembly code if there is really a jump to your function?

Comment: ICC implements a number of GCC extensions - try adding: `__attribute__ ((__always_inline__))` to the function specification.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Nope. Only direct function invocations.

Comment: @Angew Yes, the function definition is included from a header file, thus accessible at compile time.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the call site? I mean, just call the function outside of a loop or other nesting. See if the compiler is willing to inline it at least in the most simple setup.

Comment: @BrettHale Do you mean `__attribute__((always_inline))`? Tried both, not working..

Comment: @Massa Tried, not working :(

Comment: @MikeMB No I haven't checked the assembly. But I've tried converting this function to a macro, and got a noticeable performance boost. So I'm rather sure the function is not inlined.

Comment: @Angew Tried your suggestion, still no difference.

Comment: what if you mark the function inline static? Otherwise it will be required to have linkage?

Comment: @lei.april That sounds reasonable, which unfortunately means that I've no Idea, why the compiler doesn't want to inline the function.
However, as you're already using compiler specific types in the function interfaces, I wonder, why you want to put the call to _mm512_add_pd inside a function in the first place?

Comment: @MikeMB Well, that's another story. There're two data types representing SIMD registers, `__m512d` for floating-points and `__m512i` for integers. In my example I only demonstrated the former. Actually I'd like to utilize function overloading to handle these two types with a single function name `vec_add`, and that's why I avoid using macros.

Comment: @paulm Well, it doesn't help...

Comment: Read Assembly code. The whole discussion is useless unless you provide non-inlined Assembly code. BTW, I hope that you are talking about Release configuration with optimizations turned on.

Comment: One thing you could try is this: Pass the arguments by value and return the result via a return statement and see what happens (check again for inlining and execution speed).

Comment: @AlexFarber As mentioned above, `-O3` is used in my configuration. The assembly is a bit overwhelming to me(shame on me..). Please see the code I've just posted and maybe you can compile and disassemble it.

Comment: @ Tried, no help. BTW, I've just posted a complete code snippet. You can try other ideas on it.

Comment: @lei.april The two important things about your code are the offloading pragma and `__attribute((target(mic)))` directive (see my answer). If you do stuff like this and your compiler doesn't behave as expected, you should really mention it in your question

Comment: @MikeMB Never thought the pragma would cause such problem... The link you found is really helpful. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @lei.april Sorry, maybe my last comment was a little harsh. After all: If we always knew what causes our problems, we would hardly need stackoverflow right? Anyway, glad I could help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason the Intel Compiler doesn't do inlining of functions in offloaded code (I'm not all that familiar with the concept, so I don't know what the technical reason for this is).
See [effective-use-of-the-intel-compilers-offload-features](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/effective-use-of-the-intel-compilers-offload-features) for more information (just search for "inline").

Quoting from the linked article:

> Function Inlining into Offload Constructs
>
> Sometimes inlining a function is necessary for optimum performance of
>   the generated code. **Functions called directly within a #pragma offload**
>   **are not inlined by the compiler even if they are marked as inline**. To
>   enable optimum performance of code in offload regions, either manually
>   inline functions, or place the entire offload construct into its own
>   function.
>
> ...
>
> One solution is to manually inline function f, as shown in function
>   v2.
>
> Another solution is to move the offload construct into its own
>   function as shown in function v3.

If I understand this correctly, the best thing to do for you would be to place the loops into a separate function which is also marked with __attribute((target(mic))).

Comment: I presume that this is simply a limitation of the current implementation, and not a design intention.